# I'm really bad at math and I want to do a binary operation

Tags: c#, binary-operators

I have the following piece of code:

```
    public void AddHash( int val )
    {
        m_Hash ^= (val & 0x3FFFFFF);
        m_Hash ^= (val >> 26) & 0x3F;
    }
```

I would like very much to know what the heck it does, but I would be satisfied to know how to build a `bool HasHash( int val )` that tells me whether m_Hash has that number or not...

something like this?

```
    public bool HasHash( int val )
    {
        return (m_Hash & val) == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Wikipedia has a good page on bitwise operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT to fix the bug that @schnaader found:** What it does? This code probably ***wants*** to rotate `val` leftwards (clockwise) by 6 bits and form the ones-complement sum *(edit: not the product, as I'd said before)* -- the xor -- of that rotated value and the current value of `m_Hash` to yield a new `m_Hash`. That new `m_Hash` will be used the next time `AddHash( )` is called.

However, the code as written has a bug: it rotates only the high-order 6 bits of `val` leftwards, leaving in place the low-order 26 bits of `val`. The code then xors together three values:

1. the new low-order (old high-order) 6 bits of `val`;
2. the original, unshifted low-order 26 bits of `val`; and
3. the current value of `m_Hash`

leaving the result in `m_Hash`.

How does it do it? You can just map it out and emulate it:

1. `val & 0x3FFFFFF` means extract the low-order 26 bits of `val`.
2. `xor` those 26 bits with the current value of `m_Hash`
3. now shift `val` rightwards such that the low-order 26 bits drop off the low-order end, leaving what used to be the high-order 6 bits of `val` in the low-order 6 bits of `val`.
4. Mask with `0x3f` to extract only those low-order 6 bits (in case some extraneous bits got shifted into the high order part of `val`).
5. `xor` those low-order 6 bits with the current value of `m_Hash` to give the new `m_Hash`.

You know that rotating and exclusive-oring are common operations in calculating a hash.

**EDIT:** @schnaader pointed out the bug in the original code: that code forgot to do the other leg of the rotate: shifting the low-order 26 bits left by 6. To fix that, the code should read something like:

```
public void AddHash( int val )
{
  m_Hash ^= ((val & 0x3FFFFFF) << 6);
  m_Hash ^= (val >> 26) & 0x3F;
}
```

As to your `HasHash( )` function: you should know that saying

`return (m_Hash & val) == 0;`

will return TRUE under many conditions, including some you might not want. For example, the function will return TRUE if `m_Hash == 0xC0` and `val == 0x03`.

Answer (score 3):

*What the code does*

It takes the last 26 bits of `val` and combines it with `m_Hash` using [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations#XOR). After that, it combines this with the first 6 bits of `val`. So an integer with 32 bits length will be reduced to 26 bits. According to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), this is **not** reversible.

*HasHash function*

So you won't be able to create a `HasHash` function even if you only called `AddHash` just once, because multiple input values in `val` will result in the same `m_hash` value.